# Saving gchat history while using sleekxmpp

Tags: python, xmpp

I'm trying to run the sample code provided in "XMPP: The Definitive Guide", I found out I can successfully echo the message others send to me, but my reply is not saved in gchat history.

I googled a little bit, and found out I need to set archivingenabled to True in Usersettings, but I can't find out how can I do this using sleekxmpp.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Here is the code

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from secret import USER, PD
import sleekxmpp, logging, sys
logging.basicConfig()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') #@UndefinedVariable

class EchoBot : 
    def __init__(self, jid, password) : 
        self.xmpp = sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP(jid, password) 
        self.xmpp.add_event_handler("session_start", self.handleXMPPConnected) 
        self.xmpp.add_event_handler("message", self.handleIncomingMessage) 
        print self.xmpp.settings

    def run(self) : 
        self.xmpp.connect() 
        self.xmpp.process(threaded=True) 

    def handleXMPPConnected(self, event): 
        self.xmpp.sendPresence()

    def handleIncomingMessage(self, message):
        self.xmpp.sendMessage(message["from"], message["body"]) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = EchoBot(USER, PD)
    bot.run()
```